# Core Data: Fetching all entity objects having to-many-relationship object with certain value

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have the following relationship in Core Data:
[image]

What's the correct `NSPredicate` to get all courses having at least one student over the age of 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY students.age > %d", 25]
```

should work (as predicate for a fetch request for the "Course" entity).

Comment: Thanks, ANY was the keyword I was looking for.